# When Typescript's AllowJs flag is enabled is there a way to safely overwrite source files?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

--allowJs would currently overwrite our js files, we want this behavior as they are being transpiled. Is there a way to confirm the overwrite>

Comment: Look at the first option here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `--outDir` to not worry about overwritting of something by TypeScript.